# Get Canceled Orders with specified range using magento soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, api, soap

Can anyone help me how to get the Canceled orders of specified range in magento1.9 soap api.

Iam getting the orders but time exausting so i wants to get the orders between range.

Find the below code to get orders of status canceled:

```
$filter = array('filter' => array(array('key' => 'status', 'value' => 'canceled')));
$result = $client->salesOrderList($session, $filter);
```

Thanks

Thanks